# 2 or 3 matrices side-by-side

Tags: math-mode, matrices

[image]

How to write the above 2 and 3 matrices side-by-side in Latex ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's normally very helpful if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates shows what you have so far. Then people can directly add the solution.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I have learnt how to write a 2*2 matrix in Latex only. I have no idea about writing matrices side-by-side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be no mystery to this, just put several matrices after each other in a display.  The standard [`amsmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the convenient `pmatrix` for matrices with brackets, as well as a wealth of other useful constructions for mathematics; see also the [`mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) which makes some useful additions.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A simple matrix conjugation is a follows
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1&0\\
    0&2
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon&b'\\
    0&\eta
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1&0\\
    0&2
  \end{pmatrix}
  ^{-1}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon&b'/2\\
    0&\eta
  \end{pmatrix}
  .
\end{equation*}
Here is a similarity relation.
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon&b\\
    0&\eta
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon&b'\\
    0&\eta
  \end{pmatrix}
  .
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using macros for repeatable patterns may be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\def\epse#1{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\epsilon& #1\\
0 &\eta
\end{array}
\right)}

\def\onet{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1& 0\\
0 &2
\end{array}
\right)}


\begin{gather*}
\onet\epse{b'}\onet^{-1}=\epse{2b'}\\[6pt]
\epse{b}\sim\epse{b'}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this a bit too complex for a beginner's question.