# Adding arrows between rows of an equation LaTex

Tags: equations, arrows

I am a LaTex beginner and I am writing my first formal document.
I need to add some arrows in an equation. Let me show you my code:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w) & = \underline{(\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w})} + \underline{(\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w})} + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (x\bar{y}zw) + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xyzw) \\
              &\eqtnine (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}) + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + \underline{(x\bar{y}zw)} + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + \underline{(xyzw)} \\
         &\eqtnine (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}) + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xzw) \\
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

And this is the current result:
[image]

As you can see two terms are underlined every row and I'd like to have some arrows to start under that terms and their heads to be over a term which is on another line as I show in the following picture which I made using paint:
[image]

Is there an easy way to do it? Thank you in advance for your patience and consideration.

Edit: Here you are console log for the error using code I found in the answer:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 258--259

''''[2]
Chapter 2.
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.284 \end{align}

?
```

Comment: Try with `tikzmark` library from `tikz` package.

Comment: Have you got an example to show me please?

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361375/108724). @Zarko: the `tikzmark` library is a bit confusing even for me, so isn't it better to write an answer rather than a comment for such new users?

Comment: @C.F.G, if I had time then. I will try to write late in the evening if it will be still relevant.

Comment: You could add a minimal working example (compilable)?

Answer (score 3):

I propose this  pstricks`solution, based on the`\psDefBoxNodes{name}{contents}`, which measures the bounding box of its content, and defines 12 associated nodes, and the node connecting command`\ncangle`. As the verical spacing is limited, we have to adjust the value of various parameters by trial and error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\newcommand{\eqtnine}{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{T9}}{ = }}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w) & = \psDefBoxNodes{A}{\underline{(\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w})}} + \psDefBoxNodes{B}{\underline{(\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w})}} + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (x\bar{y}zw) + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xyzw) \\
              &\eqtnine(\bar{x} \psDefBoxNodes{C}{\bar{y}\bar{z}})+ (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + \psDefBoxNodes{D}{\underline{(x\bar{y}zw)}} + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) +\psDefBoxNodes{E}{ \underline{(xyzw)}} \\
         &\eqtnine (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}) + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + \psDefBoxNodes{F}{(xzw)} \\
\end{split}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=->,arrowinset=0.12, armB=6pt, angleA=-90, angleB=90, nodesepA=-0.5pt, nodesepB=2pt}
\ncline[arrows=-, offsetB=1pt]{A:bC}{C:tC}\ncangle[offsetB=1pt, nodesepB=1pt]{B:bC}{C:tC}
\psset{nodesepB =-1.5pt}
\ncangle{D:bC}{F:tC}\ncangle{E:bC}{F:tC}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I edited my question with console log

Comment: The problem is that  `pdflatex` cannot make the computations required by the postscript language (albeit pdf is a subset of postscript, compressed). You have 3 solutions: follow the classic method: `latex+dvips+pstopdf`, or load the `aupst-pdf`  package (*after* pstricks) and compile with the switch --shell-escape  too delegate the calculations, or compile with `xelatex` (I used the last solution).

Answer (score 1):

With `tikzmark` (as I noted in my comment), just arrows between terms in the last two equations (as starting point):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w) 
    & = (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w}) 
            + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (x\bar{y}zw) + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (xyzw) \\[3ex]
    & = (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}) + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) 
            + \tikzmarknode{A}{(x\bar{y}zw)} + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) 
            + \tikzmarknode{B}{(xyzw)}                           \\[3ex]
    & = (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}) + (\bar{x}y\bar{z}\bar{w}) 
            + (xy\bar{z}\bar{w}) + \tikzmarknode{C}{(xzw)}
\end{split}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
                    arr/.style={->,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}
                    ]
\draw[thick, gray]   
        (A.south west) -- (A.south east)
        (B.south west) -- (B.south east);
\draw[arr] (A.south) -- + (0,-2ex) -| (C.north);
\draw[arr] (B.south) -- + (0,-2ex) -| (C.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*

- Please always instead of code fragment provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small, compilable document, which demonstrate your problem and which we can test as it is.
- In MWE preamble are information about your document pages layout, your definition (for example definition for `\eqtnine`, instead it I use `=`)
- Connection between terms of the first two equation I left to you. From given example it should be straightforward to add them.
- For showed result you need to compile document at least twice.