# Column headings on the table border

Tags: tables

I'm reproducing an old textbook but I can't manage to typeset the tables.
The column headings, or the title of the table, should be placed on the border itself.

Here are a two examples:

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

The first one corresponds to the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \fbox{
    \begin{tabular}{llll|lll}
      & & SINGULIER & & & PLURIEL \\
      & & & & & \\
      & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE \\
      \textsc{Nom.} & \emph{is} & \emph{ea} & \emph{id} & \emph{ei} ou \emph{ii} & \emph{eæ} & \emph{ea}
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{document}
```

I have neither included the accents nor the following lines as they are unrelated to the question.

Comment: Could you post what you tried, that we don't have to retype everything? Do you really want to type a Latin grammar?

Comment: Sure, but you can use dummy text if needed

Comment: Yes, it's an old Latin grammar book of about a hundred pages, why?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Typeset the table normally, including the headers.
- Add `\tikznode` commands for each header 'on the line'.
- Wrap the whole `tabular` into a `\tikznode` command.
- Add a `tikzpicture` to draw the lines.

The `\tikznode` command is defined and described in [this answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998).

For fine-tuning, use the optional argument of `\tikznode` to supply options to tikz. E.g., for adding more space around the tabular and the headers, you can define two styles by

```
\tikzset{tab/.style={inner sep=2pt},hdr/.style={inner xsep=4pt}}
```

and add `tab` and `hdr` as options to the `\tikznode` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\tikzset{tab/.style={inner sep=2pt},hdr/.style={inner xsep=4pt}}
\begin{document}
\tikznode[tab]{singplu}{%
  \begin{tabular}{llll|lll}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\tikznode[hdr]{sing}{SINGULIER}} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tikznode[hdr]{plu}{PLURIEL}} \\
    & & & & & \\
    & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE \\
    \textsc{Nom.} & \emph{is} & \emph{ea} & \emph{id} & \emph{ei} ou \emph{ii} & \emph{eæ} & \emph{ea}
  \end{tabular}%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw (singplu.south west) |- (sing);
  \draw (sing) -- (plu);
  \draw (plu) -| (singplu.south east);
  \draw (singplu.south east) -- (singplu.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will consider trying to automate the process but I accepted the solution, thank you

Comment: I may regret having made this comment later, but I do not think that it is a good idea to nest `tikzpicture`s. Note also that the `tikzmark` library defines a `\tikzmarknode` command. Finally, while I did not try I'd think that `nicematrix` could be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{:}{!{\vrule}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|llll:lll|}
\Hline
\noalign{\vspace{4mm}}
  & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE & MASCULIN & FÉMININ & NEUTRE \\
  \textsc{Nom.} & \emph{is} & \emph{ea} & \emph{id} & \emph{ei} ou \emph{ii} & \emph{eæ} & \emph{ea} \\
\noalign{\vspace{1mm}}
\Hline
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (1-|1) -- node [fill=white] {SINGULIER} (1-|5) 
            (1-|5) -- node [fill=white] {PLURIEL} (1-|8) ;
\end{NiceTabular}%

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]