# How to have multiple arrows pointing from individual parts of one equation to another?

Tags: arrows

I want to get a similar and simple effect like this that doesn't involve crazy arrow curves or packages.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm adapting [my answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998) to your example; check it out for some explanations. Basically, you have to

- wrap all parts that you want to reference in the drawing commands into a `\tikznode` command, which assigns a name to it and stores the size of the box
- add a `tikzpicture` environment starting with

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,...]
  ```

  that contains the draw commands.
- run LaTeX twice to get the positions right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
   {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
      \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
   }
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \tikznode{PT}{$P_{T}$} &=
  \tikznode{PB0}{$P^{0}_{B}$}+X_{A}(\tikznode{diff}{$\underbrace{P^{0}_{A}-P^{0}_{B}}$}) \\[2ex]
  \tikznode{y}{$y$} & =  \tikznode{a}{$a$}+ \tikznode{b}{$b$}\cdot x
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,cyan,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
  \draw[->] (PT) -- (y);
  \draw[->] (PB0) -- (a);
  \draw[->] (diff) -- +(0,-0.5) -| (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do the stealth and shorten parts do?

Comment: @Anush Remove or change it, and you will see. `stealth` is a particular type of arrow (looking like these fighter planes, stealth bombers); if you remove `>=stealth`, you get the default type of arrows. `shorten <` and `shorten >` reduce the lines at the beginning and at the end by the given amount. Otherwise the lines would start directly from and end at the borders of the object. For more information, see the `tikz` manual.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of many solution to create your image...I have not used `TikZ` but a simple environment `array`.  Just to be correct considering that the moving of the characters was done manually with `\mkern`, whenever you added something the arrows would move and not be aligned as in the example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
P_{T} &= P^{0}_{B}+X_{A}(\underbrace{P^{0}_{A}-P^{0}_{B}}) \\[-.4ex]
\downarrow & \quad \downarrow \mkern85mu \swarrow\\
y & =  a+\mkern50mu b\cdot x
\end{array}   
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, but, in the question, the two *P^{0}_{B}* are the same, and those look more like *P_{A}^{0}* and *P_{B}^{0}* to me. This would perfect the answer.

Comment: @niamulbengali You have right :-(...I often do a mix of the sub-over script :-(

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, bm} 
\newcommand{\mathbsf}[1]{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}
\usepackage{pst-node} 

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \rnode{PT}{P_T} & ={} & \rnode{PB}{P_B⁰} & + X_A\bigl(\underbrace{P_A-P_B^0}_{\pnode[-3pt, 1.5ex]{PAB}}\bigr) \\[1.5ex]
\rnode{y}{\mathbsf{y}} & ={} & \rnode{a}{\mathbsf{a}} & \mathbin{\mathbsf{+}} \rnode{b}{\mathbsf{b}}\cdot \mathbsf{x}
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, linecolor=DeepSkyBlue, nodesep=1pt}
\ncline{PT}{y}
\ncline{PB}{a}
\ncline{PAB}{b}
 \end{alignat*}

\end{document} }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be to use the tikz to make arrows in the equation like example below.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (E1) at (0,0.71) {$P_{T} = P^{0}_{B}+X_{A}(\underbrace{P^{0}_{A}-P^{0}_{B}})$};
        \node (E2) at (0,0) {$Y = A + B X$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.7,.6)--(-0.1,0.2); 
        \draw[->,thick] (1.2,.5)--(0.6,0.2); 
        \draw[->,thick] (-1.7,.7)--(-1.1,0.2); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Good luck

[image]