# Adjust the arrows between the nodes of two matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to reproduce the figure but I am unable to adjust the arrows between the nodes of the matrices

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
\tikzset{arrow style mul/.style={circle,midway,fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [thick,baseline=(A.center),>=stealth,
   every left  delimiter/.append style={name=rd},thick]

    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]                    
           (A) at (0,0) { 
                         |[red]| a   &  |[blue]|b    \\
                          c          &          d    \\
    };

    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
            (P) at (4cm,0) { 
                            |[green]| ae + bf \\
                             ce + df \\
    };

   \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
            (B) at (4cm,2cm) { 
                              |[red]|  e \\
                              |[blue]| f \\
   };

  \draw[red,->](A.north -|A-1-1) --
       node[arrow style mul] (x) {$\times$} (rd.west|-B-1-1.center);
  \draw[blue,->](A.north -|A-1-2) --
       node[arrow style mul] (x) {$\times$} (rd.west|-B-2-1.center);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it better with the answer below -- removed the white fil in the label over the arrow and instead of midway made it 4 pts above the arrow

Comment: added the third arrow also which was left out yesterday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adapting [my answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998) to your example; check it out for some explanations. Basically, you have to

- typeset the mathematical part (the matrices)
- wrap all parts that you want to reference in the drawing commands into a `\tikznode` command, which assigns a name to it and stores the size of the box as well as its position
- add a `tikzpicture` environment starting with

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,...]
  ```

  that contains the drawing commands.
- run LaTeX twice to get the positions right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}

\( \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l}
     & \begin{pmatrix}
       \tikznode[red ]{e}{$e$} \\
       \tikznode[blue]{f}{$f$}
     \end{pmatrix}
   \\[5ex]
     \begin{pmatrix}
       \tikznode[red]{a}{$a$} & \tikznode[blue]{b}{$b$} \\
                 c            &             d
     \end{pmatrix}
   & \begin{pmatrix}
       \tikznode[green]{ae+bf}{$ae+bf$} \\
                  ce + df
     \end{pmatrix}     
   \end{array}
\)
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  rounded corners,
  >=stealth,
  thick
  ]
  \draw[->,red  ,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=6pt]
    (a) to[out=80,in=-180] node[above]{$\times$} (e);
  \draw[->,blue ,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=6pt]
    (b) to[out=80,in=-180] node[above,pos=0.4]{$\times$} (f);
  \draw[<-,green,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=6pt]
    (ae+bf) |- ++(-1.3,0.5) node{$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the compilation returns an error `! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.`

Comment: @Fabrice Which document yields this error? If I copy my code into a new file and run latex, I get no error. If you get an error with my code, it's maybe necessary to update your LaTeX system. If your own code gives this error, it is difficult to guess the reason without seeing the code.

Comment: Your code but with this `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} ` because I have to insert the figure in my course.

Comment: Replace `\[ ... \]` by `\( ... \)`. `standalone` does not like environments and commands that rely on the text width; alternatively, you can use the `varwidth` option of standalone. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}
\tikzset{arrow style mul/.style={circle,yshift=4pt,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [thick,baseline=(A.center),>=stealth,
   every left  delimiter/.append style={name=rd},thick]

    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]                    
           (A) at (0,0) { 
                         |[red]| a   &  |[blue]|b    \\
                          c          &          d    \\
    };

    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
            (P) at (4cm,0) { 
                            |[green]| ae + bf \\
                             ce + df \\
    };

   \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
            (B) at (4cm,2cm) { 
                              |[red]|  e \\
                              |[blue]| f \\
   };

  \draw[red,->](A.north -|A-1-1) --
       node[arrow style mul] (x1) {$\times$} (rd.west|-B-1-1.center);
  \draw[blue,->](A.north -|A-1-2) --
       node[arrow style mul] (x2) {$\times$} (rd.west|-B-2-1.center);
       \coordinate(a)at($(x2)+(0,-12pt)$);
\draw[green,->](a)node[left]{+}-|(P.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion