# Latex: How to write single cross arrow in a 2x2 matrix?

Tags: diagrams, matrices, arrows

[image: sample]

Is there a way to make a version of the diagram provided above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adapting my [answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998); see there for some explanations on how to draw arrows between text elements.

- First, typeset the text without arrows.
- Wrap all elements, that will be the origin or target of an arrow, into a `\tikznode` command. This assigns a name to the text element and stores its size and position.
- Add a `tikzpicture` environment with the options `remember picture,overlay` below. It contains the graphical elements, in this case the arrows. Here you will use the names assigned in the previous step.
- Run LaTeX at least two times to propagate the information about the nodes and arrows everywhere.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% only needed for the arrow tip stealth'
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\qquad}r}
    \tikznode{-x}{$-x$} & \tikznode{1}{$1$} \\[2ex]
    \tikznode{2x}{$2x$} & \tikznode{3}{$3$} \\
    \cline{2-2}
                        & $-x$
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,> = stealth',shorten <= 4pt,shorten > = 4pt]
  \draw[->] (-x.east) -- (3.west);
  \draw[->] (2x.east) -- (1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to the classical environment `{array}` (of `array`) but creates PGF nodes under the cells of the array. Then, it's possible to use Tikz to draw the required arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{r@{\qquad}r}
    -x & 1 \\[2ex]
    2x & 3 \\
    \cline{2}
         & -x
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten <= 4pt,shorten > = 4pt]
  \draw[->] (1-1.east) -- (2-2.west);
  \draw[->] (2-1.east) -- (1-2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Is it possible to put a NiceArray inside a figure caption?