# Underset arrows of various lengths in aligned equation

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, tikz-arrows, arrows

I'm trying since some time now to get the following (see picture) done in `LaTeX`.

But I don't even have code that works so far, as all I've found by searching the internet wasn't helpful (I'm not even sure what to search for `tbh`).

I'd like the t's to be aligned with the v's and then draw the arrows like shown below.
That `t_1 \in T` on the left side, isn't that important, as I'll just write that down below :)

I'm really stuck so any help would be appreciated!

[image]

---

EDIT:
I've got the alignment although that isn't good practice I guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        &cv_1 &&cv_2 &\ldots &&&cv_i &\ldots &&&&cv_j  &&\ldots &&&&&cv_k\\
        &t_1  &&t_2 &\ldots &&&t_i &\ldots &&&&t_j  &&\ldots &&&&&t_k
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not try tikz?

Comment: Tryed but couldn't do it...my tikz skills are too low i guess :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with a simple `array` environment and`pstricks`; the letters to be linked are defined as nodes in this array, and connected with `\ncangle` with the relevant parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{array}{*{9}{r}}
     cv_1 &cv_2 &\ldots &cv_i &\ldots &cv_j &\ldots &cv_k\\
     t_1 & \rnode{T2}{t_2} &\ldots & \rnode{Ti}{t_i }&\ldots &\rnode{Tj}{t_j} &\ldots &t_k \\[0.5ex]
     & & & & & & & & \makecell{\rnode{Aj}{\varphi}\\\rnode{Ai}{\varphi}\\\rnode{A2}{\varphi}}
    \end{array}
    \psset{linewidth=0.6pt, linejoin=1, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, angleA=-90, angleB=180, nodesep=3pt}
    \foreach \s in {2,i, j}{\ncangle{T\s}{A\s}}
     \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a nice solution! Thank you a lot! :) I get "undefined controll sequence" tho when using it, because "\ncangle" isn't known?

Comment: It is documented. Maybe you compiled with pdflatex?

Comment: Ahm yes....ok so thats not working...gonna change it..thanks :) Edit: That solved it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Use xelatex, it will be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adapting my [answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998); see there for some explanations on how to use Tikz to draw arrows between text elements.

- First, typeset the text without arrows.
- Wrap all elements, that will be the origin or target of an arrow, into a `\tikznode` command. This assigns a name to the text element and stores its size and position.
- Add a `tikzpicture` environment with the options `remember picture,overlay` below. It contains the graphical elements, in this case the arrows. Here you will use the names assigned in the previous step.
- Run LaTeX at least two times to propagate the information about the nodes and arrows everywhere.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% only needed for the arrow tip stealth'
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{array}{*{9}{r}}
     cv_1 &cv_2 &\ldots &cv_i &\ldots &cv_j &\ldots &cv_k\\
     t_1 & \tikznode{T2}{$t_2$} &\ldots & \tikznode{Ti}{$t_i$}&\ldots &\tikznode{Tj}{$t_j$} &\ldots &t_k \\[0.5ex]
         & & & & & & & & \tikznode{Aj}{$\varphi$} \\
         & & & & & & & & \tikznode{Ai}{$\varphi$} \\
         & & & & & & & & \tikznode{A2}{$\varphi$}
       \end{array}
     \]%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,> = stealth',shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt]
  \draw[->] (T2) |- (A2);
  \draw[->] (Ti) |- (Ai);
  \draw[->] (Tj) |- (Aj);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```