# Package to draw visual explanations?

Tags: math-mode, packages

I am looking for packages to write visual explanations of algorithms and math stuff. My main question is:

Do you know any packages that do any of the examples below?

I would like to do what is done in the image below but with highlighting and pointing arrows instead of colouring the text.

[image: https://agilescientific.com/blog/2020/2/25/visual-explanations-of-mathematics]
https://agilescientific.com/blog/2020/2/25/visual-explanations-of-mathematics

Here are some other examples of what I am looking for:

[image: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03908.pdf]
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03908.pdf

[image: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=pW--cu2FCHY]
https://openreview.net/pdf?id=pW--cu2FCHY

Comment: MetaPost, TikZ, pstricks and many others. It depends on your taste. Honestly I'm bored by so many TikZ examples on this site, but, as more users master it, you could ask to them.

Comment: Yeah, `tikz`for the drawings along with the `tikzmark` for drawing arrows. Many examples on this site.

Comment: See e.g. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998), or [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580835](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580835/110998)