# Logical conditional proof (c.p.) arrows

Tags: texlive, logic, logicproof

How can I write down that line from horizontal, then vertical and with an arrow pointing at argument 2?

[image: conditional proof]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an explanation of the `\tikznode` command see
[my answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% defines \therefore
\let\impl\supset
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
      \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rll}
              1.  & $A\impl B$ \rlap{\quad$/\therefore A\impl (A\cdot B)$}\\
 \tikznode{A}{2.} & $A$                & supuesto \\
              3.  & $B$                & $1$, $2$, M.P.\\
              4.  & $A\cdot B$                        & $2$, $3$, Conj.\\
              5.  & \tikznode{B}{$A\impl(A\cdot B)$\strut} & $2$--$4$, C.P.
   \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[stealth-,shorten <=2pt] (A) -- ++(-1.5em,0) |- (B.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely right! This is pretty much what I needed.Thank you so much!

Comment: @gernot, your answer is more than excellent. However, in the picture that mao2047 has included (and in general all examples of this style of expressing conditional proofs), the (horizontal) part of the arrow shaft extends from the left margin to just above the end of the following line's assertion (in this case, the **)** of line 5 ( ` \A\impl(A\cdot B)\ ` ). Is there a way to do this, if not automatically, then at least without guessing and doing quick and dirty trial-and-error? (Please let me know if my comment doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @NoahJ You are right, this horizontal line is too short. See my adapted solution. I switched to a `tabular` environment, as this makes the code a bit simpler, but you can also use an `array`, but then may need `\text` from the `mathtools` package.

Comment: @gernot I just wrote some macro definitions that, while using basically your solution, simplify what the writer must input, but they're too lengthy for me to include all of them here. For example:

`\newcounter{lineno} % as in ``line number''`
`\newcommand{\copiproof}[1]{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{rll}\setcounter{lineno}{0}#1\end{tabular}\end{center}} % after Irving Copi`
`\newcommand{\premise}[1]{\addtocounter{lineno}{1}\thelineno. & $#1$\\}`

Do I have your permission to write a Q&A style question so that I can give all of the definitions, if I credit you?

Comment: @NoahJ This is all open, use it as you like, with or without credits.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, based on an `enumerate` environment, the `eqparbox` package  and `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{%
\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[wide =2em, labelsep=1em, nosep]
    \item $A\supset B \quad/\therefore A\supset(A\cdot B)$
    \item\pnode[-2em, 0.8ex]{2} \eqmathbox{E} supuesto
    \item \eqmathbox{B} 1, 2, M. P.
    \item \eqmathbox{A\cdot B} 2, 3, Conj.
    \item \eqmathbox{A\supset (A\cdot B)\pnode[-0.75ex, 2.2ex]{A}\quad} 2–4, C. P.
    \ncbar[linecolor=LightSlateGray, linejoin=1, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, angle=180]{A}{2}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \therefore
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,ext.paths.ortho} % for "r-lr"

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rll}
  1.  & $A\supset B$ \rlap{\quad$/\therefore A\supset (A\cdot B)$}\\
  2.  & $A$                  & supuesto \\
  3.  & $B$                  & $1$, $2$, M.P.\\
  4.  & $A\cdot B$               & $2$, $3$, Conj.\\
  5.  & $A\supset(A\cdot B)$     & $2$--$4$, C.P.
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw [<-,shorten < = 2pt] (2-1) r-lr ([yshift=1pt]5-|3);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]