# Using tikz and tipa packages

Tags: tikz-styles, tipa

I'm using the packages `tipa` and `tikz` in the document class `beamer`. However, I'm having a hard time trying to combine them when drawing arrows. Look at the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz} % if i remove package from preamble i get error message


\begin{document}
    
    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
    \tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,text depth=0pt]
    
    \begin{frame}

        \centering
        
        Text [ t ] more text [ \textsubbridge{t} ]
        
        \vspace{2em}
        
        symbol 1 and symbol 2
    
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}

        \centering
        
        Text [ \tikz\node[na](t1){t}; ] more text [ \tikz\node[na](t2){\textsubbridge{t}}; ]
        
        \vspace{2em}
        
        \tikz\node[na](n1){symbol 1}; and \tikz\node[na](n2){symbol 2};
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \path[->,red,thick](n1) edge (t1);
            \path[->,red,thick](n2) edge (t2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Slide with no arrows:

[image]

Slide with arrows:

[image]

As you can see, when I add the arrow, it blocks part of the symbol, which is an important part of the symbol. How can I lower the arrow so that it doesn't cover any part of the second symbol?

PS: I know that beamer automatically loads the `tikz` package. However, for this MWE I kept getting an error if I don't load it manually. I believe it has to do with the definition of the `tikzstyle{na}`, but if I'm wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: (Unrelated to the actual question, but) if you have access to Xe/LuaLaTeX, using package [`tipauni`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni) might be advisable as it will render searchable|copy-able|past-able Unicode characters in the output. If you want the `beamer` fonts to be intact, you can `\usepackage[documentfont=CMUSansSerif]{tipauni}`.

Comment: @Niranjan, I just tried loading this package, and I got the following error: `File tipauni.sty not found. ^^M`. I'm assuming that means I don't have access to Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: No. This means that you need the `tipauni.sty` i.e. the actual package file. You might be using an old installation. From TeX Live 2022 onward `tipauni` will be by default present. If you are using TeX Live 2021, please try `tlmgr install tipauni`. For installing the package locally; you can follow the instructions given [here](https://mail.gnu.org.ua/mailman/listarchive/tipauni-help/2022-01/msg00001.html). Also simply adding the line in your code might not change the compiler. You have to manually change it from PDFLaTeX to Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `beamer` class doesn't load `tikz` automatically, which explains why it has to be loaded.
- `\tikzstyle` is deprecated in favor of `\tikzset`.
- Your problem is caused by `text depth=0pt`. Probably you do that to align the characters on the baseline, but this can be achieved using the `baseline` option.
- To make text elements the source or target of arrows, you can use the `\tikznode` command described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998). It corresponds roughly to your `\tikz\node[na]` (with the above problems removed).
- To keep a bit of distance between the arrows and their targets, you can use the options `shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt`.
- You might prefer other arrow heads, like `\tikzset{>=stealth}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
   {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
      \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
   }
\tikzset{%
   every picture/.append style={remember picture},
   >=stealth  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
Text [ \tikznode{t1}{t} ] more text [ \tikznode{t2}{\textsubbridge{t}} ]
\vspace{2em}
        
\tikznode{n1}{symbol 1} and \tikznode{n2}{symbol 2}
        
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt]
   \path[->,red,thick](n1) edge (t1);
   \path[->,red,thick](n2) edge (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks for the pointers re: tikz conventions. Also, it looks like in your code the `;` is no longer needed at the end when defining the node.

Comment: @Ernesto Thanks for the note regarding the semicolons, I removed them.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that the [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library has a command `\tikzmarknode` that can replace your `\tikz\node...;` and can deal automatically with different math modes and with the conflicts between TikZ and the babel package, to name just two.

Also, although the arrows are typeset in a tikzpicture with the `overlay` option set, they do still introduce a TeX box which adjusts the spacing. By introducing a few `%`s at judicious places, that box can be put in a place where it doesn't affect the spacing (without making your source code unreadable).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630413/86}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}

        \centering
        
        Text [ t ] more text [ \textsubbridge{t} ]
        
        \vspace{2em}
        
        symbol 1 and symbol 2
    
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}

        \centering
        
        Text [ \tikzmarknode{t1}{t} ] more text [ \tikzmarknode{t2}{\textsubbridge{t}} ]
        
        \vspace{2em}
        
        \tikzmarknode{n1}{symbol 1} and \tikzmarknode{n2}{symbol 2}%
        % <- here and on previous line to avoid the arrows adding space
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \path[->,red,thick](n1) edge (t1);
            \path[->,red,thick](n2) edge (t2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and concise!