Making space for contents inserted by tikzpicture

As you see, the text inserted by tikzpicture overlaps with the previous text
My MWE
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
% BEGIN_FOLD
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}

% highlight every node
% BEGIN_FOLD

\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {
        draw, rectangle,
        line width=0.1pt,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw opacity=0.1,
    }
}

% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

{\color{gray}%
\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}

\begin{equation*}
    e \mathrel{\tikzmarknode{equal}{=}} m \mspace{1mu} c^{2}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        
        \node[align=left,above=1ex of equal] 
            {
                Text 1 \\ Text 2
            };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}

{\color{gray}%
\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}

\end{document}


There's a bit in the tikzmark documentation about this. It mentions https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361375/86 as an example, specifically my answer to that question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654433/86

This is something that bothered me for quite some time about tikzmark, but eventually a question here prompted me to figure it out. It now features as an example in the tikzmark documentation (as of v1.15). I'll quote it below:

One issue with placing things via \tikzmark is that the necessity of using the overlay key means that the various elements don’t take up any space. While this is needed to ensure that pictures don’t explode in size, it can be important to leave space for the additional elements. This isn’t simple. The difficulty is that \tikzmark positions depend on the previous compilation, so if we’re trying to leave space for items that depend on a previous compilation which might then affect the positions of the \tikzmarks then we can get into a loop that never settles down. The solution is to ensure that the dependency loop doesn’t arise, and that the way each measurement or position depends on others is a tree.
There are two key parts to this. The first is the \tikz command that adds a vertical strut to reserve the right vertical space. The second is the tikzpicture that defines the annotations. This defines \tikzmarks at its top and bottom extents and its baseline, but to ensure that the dependencies don’t form a loop then all are defined inside that environment even though one of them is actually at the same location as a \tikzmark defined elsewhere. This can, therefore, take more compilations than usual to settle.
This example is based on my answer to How to add arrow in equations and
matrix?.

Applying this method to your code results in:
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{book}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722041/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
% BEGIN_FOLD
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}

% highlight every node
% BEGIN_FOLD

\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {
        draw, rectangle,
        line width=0.1pt,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw opacity=0.1,
    }
}

% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

{\color{gray}%
\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}

\begin{equation*}
    e \mathrel{\tikzmarknode{equal}{=}} m \mspace{1mu} c^{2}
    %
    % This adds a strut of the calculated height
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline={(0,0)}] {\path let \p1=(pic
    cs:upper), \p3=(pic cs:middle) in
    (0,\y1-\y3);}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        
        \node[align=left,above=1ex of equal] (annotation) % label this node
            {
                Text 1 \\ Text 2
            };
            \tikzmark{upper}{(annotation.north)} % remember the node's top
            \tikzmark{middle}{(equal.base)} % remember the base of the equals sign
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}

{\color{gray}%
\noindent%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}%
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}

\end{document}



